# Reverse Proxy and SubDomains using Nginx, Docker, FastAPI and React (create-react-app) giving Invalid Host Header

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, subdomain, fastapi

I am struggling to set up an `nginx` reverse-proxy using Docker (+ docker-compose) for my `FastAPI` api and React app (made using `create-react-app`) front end. I also wish to use `nginx` to set up subdomains such that I can query `http://api.drillers` for api calls directly or http://drillers to visit the front end site. I am hosting the server on a private network.

Currently, when I run `docker-compose up` my React app and api are running fine at `localhost:3000` and `localhost:8000`, respectively. When I go to `localhost:8080`, however, I get `Invalid Host Header`. I tried following these [instructions](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) at `create-react-app` by adding `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` to `./react-app/.env.development.local` to just get it to work, but the `Invalid Host Header` error still appeared. How can I fix my `nginx` reverse proxy?

Here is the lay-out of my project:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── app
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx.conf
├── react-app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
```

FastAPI Dockerfile

```
#./api/Dockerfile
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

COPY ./app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app
```

React Dockerfile

```
#./react-app/Dockerfile

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

Nginx Dockerfile

```
#./nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf file

```
#./nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

upstream client {
    server client:
}
http {

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:3000
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name drillers.com;
        location / {
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_pass http://api.drillers;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

}
```

docker-compose

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        build: './api/.'
        volumes:
        - './api/app/drillers.db:/api/app/drillers.db'
        ports:
        - '8000:80'
        restart: always
    frontend:
        build: './react-app/.'
        ports:
        - '3000:3000'
        depends_on:
            - api
        restart: always
    nginx:
        build: './nginx/.'
        depends_on:
            - api
            - frontend
        ports:
        - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - './nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/ngninx.conf'
        restart: always
```